# setOnClickListener(this) crashes my app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I have a problem with `btn.setOnClickListener(this)`. I have a simple project that works good, but when I add an action to the button I get the message:

```
unfortunatelay (app name) has stopped
```

When I comment `btn.setOnClickListener(this)` out the project works without any problem.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {


    public static final Context PlaceholderFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
        Button btn;
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Entrer);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here is the problem error: no eclosing istance of the type MainActivityis accessible in scope
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

My layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hello.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Entrer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Entrer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I dont know if I have simple things that are not go correctly. I'm new to `Android` programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btn` is `null`, so when you set `onClickListener` you get `NullPointerException`. It's `null` because it's located in `fragment_main.xml`, not `activity_main.xml`. You should move this code from `onCreate()`

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Entrer);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

to `PlaceholderFragment()` as follows:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        btn=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Entrer);
        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Entrer);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Most likely, findViewById above is returning null.  btn.setOnClickListener is crashing on a null pointer exception. (Because btn is null).

It is extremely likely, since you are using the default fragment structure created by the Eclipse solution, that the Button is really in the fragment layout file (fragment_main.xml) and not in activity_main.xml.  (Hence, the button is not in the Activity view, it's in the fragment view).

If that's the case, then move the above two lines into the onCreateView method of the PlaceholderFragment.